# Where did the idea of modularization come from?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

I have a wild guess that science *flew* when we started to take the concepts, fragment it and examine it piece by piece, fragmenting it again when needed for a better understanding. It seems that this process of modularization was pivotal to the scientific progress but where did it come from?

I remember of having read that for centuries, euclidean geometry was a sort of perfect scientific model in which we grab the idea of certain spaces and abstract them in order to obtain their intrinsic nature and hence, they *drilled a hole* right to the axioms and confirmed that the axioms do indeed represent that idealization of space. Could this be the source?

I believe there is no *perfect* answer to this question. But I guess we could at least trace where this idea was used and have a rough estimate of its beginning. Also, I'm interested in It's existence and am looking at references on both existential and historical aspects of the concept.

Comment: The idea you describe is known in philosophy as analysis: splitting the phenomenon and analyzing its pieces. I suggest that instead of making "wild guesses" you read some history about other people's theories first.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko That is exactly what I'm asking with this question.

Comment: Why don't you begin with Wikipedia, and then ask your question.